# jQuery function running when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which only needs to run when the width is less then a specific value.  I have done this with the `if ($(window).width() < n) { }` but the function also runs when the width is more then n..

The if `if ($(window).width() < n) { }` works fine since the background color changes (light gray for < 1000px and dark gray for > 1000px).

Since the function is running also when it shouldn't the layout of my page breaks (click the tabs and then resize to see this). When the function should not run regular tabs should be displayed as you can see, they are displayed correctly until you click they toggle (which is the function getting fired whereas it shouldn't).

Anyone who can help me?

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/5f3AF/1/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5f3AF/show/) (scroll < and > 1000px to see)

PS: I am aware the  would be of a better use for although I have been limited to using a  for this.

Comment: When the window is less than `1000px` the background is light, if you make it bigger the background is darker. Smaller again and it becomes light again. The function doesn't run unless you resize the window. Seems to work as intended?

Comment: working for me too as well !

Comment: yea, the background changes; but is there something else that doesn't work?

Comment: The background change is just to 'log' if something is happening, which indeed is.. The problem is that the two functions (.schedule li & body selectors) are also running when the width is over 1000px..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `if (windowsize < 1000)` you also need to know the current status.

```
if (is_large && windowsize < 1000)
{
    is_large = false;
    // rest of code to handle transition to small size
}
else if (!is_large)
{
    is_large = true;
    // code to handle transition to large size
}
```

You also need to handle the case of setting `is_large` on page load before the initial call to `checkWidth()`.

Comment: Hi Plynx, thanks for your answer, does this mean I need to add a global is_large variable like 'var is_large = 1000;' before running the functions?

Comment: @user1901096 Global or in some singleton object somewhere, stored anywhere really. But `is_large` in this case is meant to be a boolean (true or false) not a number. It refers to what state the layout is currently in: the large layout (true), or the small layout (false). Since your code expects to run this function on page load, you need to make sure `is_large` is set to true or false depending on what layout (large or small) you've set as the default in your base HTML.