# Function within if statement also running outside of if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery function running when it shouldn’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588349/jquery-function-running-when-it-shouldnt)

have been trying to get this to work for some hours now but can't find the solution so some advice would be much appreciated! I have a function within an `if ($window.width() < 1000)` statement which also runs outside of this statement.. So when the window width is > 1000 px the function also fires.. My question is simple.. Why?

I'm 'logging' the if/else statement with the background colour which works fine, the colour changes back and forth when resizing.. When the page is < 1000px the right side list should be visually represented as a dropdown with tab functionality (same functionality as the dropdown list on the lift), and when the page is > 1000 the right side should be visually represented as tabs.

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/5f3AF/1/)

[Full screen demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5f3AF/1/show/) (makes it easier to scroll)

Comment: Your jsfiddle works for me.

Comment: Whenever the `if` statement is true, you are binding new event handlers to the element, but you are never removing them. I.e. once `$window.width() < 1000` is true, the handlers are bound to the element until you reload the page. And as said, even worse, you are *adding* new event handlers whenever the condition is true, which results in executing the same function (basically) multiple times. Solution: Either don't bind the event handlers inside the `checkWidth` function or remove them every time it is called.

Comment: @bfavaretto click on the tabs, resize to < 1000px, click on the tabs who became dropdown and resize to > 1000px again..

Comment: Well, Felix Kling found the cause.

Comment: Thanks Felix King, think I see what you mean, will try to find a solution with the info you just gave me, still quite new to jquery/javascript..

Comment: @FelixKling surely that's a fully-fledged answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: In regards to the binding, why is not ok to do this $(window).resize(checkWidth);?

Comment: On another note, would it be bad to approach this from another perspective? Something in the likes of $('.schedule li').click(function() { if ($window.width() < 1000) { //add statements} else { //empty } }); or is this not a good approach?

Answer (score 2):

The first time you open the page in a window large than 1000px it sets the click event handler. When you resize it to a width smaller than 1000px, the click event is still set, so it will still react when you click.

You can do the following:

When the width is larger than 1000px

```
$('.schedule li').bind('click', function(){...
```

else (width is smaller than 1000px) unbind the click.

```
$('.schedule li').unbind('click');
```

I hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for you answer, helpful to get me further. Did you exchange the values or am I wrong? Meaning that the bind handler should be placed in if (windowsize < 1000) and the unbind in > 1000. I update the fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/5f3AF/5/ ) but still not getting it to work..

Comment: Hi user1901096, Yes I switched the values. Sorry. Which part doesn't work?